# Can someone explain me why Disney has two different CIK's?

Tags: equities, sec

Disney, Ticker : DIS is triggering me, it seems that is has two different CIK's

If you search disney 10-K forms here:
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=company-name%3D%28DISNEY%29+and+form-type%3D%2810-K%29&first=2010&last=2020

It shows:

```
1000    Walt Disney Co  [text] [html]   10-K    11/20/2019  35176390
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/21/2018  21378552
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/22/2017  21308524
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/23/2016  20038733
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/25/2015  21091177
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/19/2014  28627599
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/20/2013  27801338
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/21/2012  21073203
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/23/2011  20047963
1000    WALT DISNEY CO/     [text] [html]   10-K    11/24/2010  23318688
```

**Walt Disney Co** -> CIK is 0001744489 , and seems to be the official one, but only contains 2019, 10-K

**WALT DISNEY CO/** -> CIK is 0001001039, and contains all other years 10-K.

Why this company has two different CIK's? is it a bug on SEC or is something that happens often?

Comment: I've answered your question, but I need to call something out that you wrote. "is it a bug on the SEC...?" If you *actually believe* this is a bug, then you should report it straight away. But given that it involves one of the largest companies in the world and has been around for a couple years, this is almost certainly **not a bug**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merger of The Walt Disney Company and Twenty-First Century Fox led to a company temporarily called [TWDC Holdco 613 Corp](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1744489/000119312518201596/d770960ds4.htm). This holding company is the *New Disney*; it's a distinct company from the *Old Disney*, aka [TWDC Enterprises 18 Corp](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1744489/000095015719000301/form8k-12b.htm). Hence the new CIK.

Comment: hi @chrisaycock thank you for the explanation, for someone developing a web scrapper this makes things harder, as multiple companies might have different CIK's in this situation, do you know any viable way to obtain all CIK's associated to a company?

Comment: @TiagoSantos That gets [asked on here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/8099/35) a lot, but [here you go](https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt).

Comment: I have checked that post, but my question was to get both CIK's associated to single ticker (ex: DIS) , these solutions only returns single CIK

Comment: @TiagoSantos You're asking for historical (point-in-time) data. If the SEC doesn't readily provide historical records, then you'll unfortunately have to rely on a vendor who has tracked the changes.