# complete historical mapping of EDGAR Central Index Key (CIK) to stock ticker

Tags: equities, edgar

I see a previous question [Central Index Key (CIK) of all traded stocks](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/central-index-key-cik-of-all-traded-stocks) mentioned https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt contains the EDGAR Central Index Key (CIK) to ticker mapping.

However, this file doesn't seem to have the historical mapping. Neither do the other answers in that question or anywhere else I saw mentioned about historical mapping.

SEC page says if a firm goes bankrupt or get bought, the CIK may be reused. So it's important to have the complete historical mapping. That is, it lists the complete mapping for each historical date from CIK to cicker.

Does a complete historical mapping exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really care about the CIKs or just the companies?

Comment: The stock symbol is what I really care.